# access SQL Query from another classes C++

Tags: sqlite, class

I have a program with SQLite database. I need to access SQL Query from another classes so I used friend keyword and defined friend classes in the SQL class.

Do you recommend me any other way to do this or is this just fine way to get the job done?

Comment: Way should class B know the entire class A? Would not just a public function that takes the query as parameter at class A do the job? That would be much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks. What do you consider as a better choice, to share the entire class  using friend or to create this friend function, which makes it cleaner but also is kind of an intermediate step?

Comment: I dont get the point why you arent just use a public function?! What is the reason to be a friend class at all? I think you dont need friend at all in this case.  May you can post a small code exmple what you exactly trying to do?